# Ввод/вывод в консоли, C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, консоль, вывод, ввод

Здравствуйте.

Решил написать небольшую RPG-игру с псевдографикой в консоли. 
Для считывания нажатий клавиш использовал функцию `GetAsyncKeyState` из `Windows.h`

```
bool isKeyPressed(int virtualKeyCode)
{
    short keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(virtualKeyCode);
    return ((keyState & 0x8000) > 0);
}
```

В функции Update проверяю состояние клавиш и изменяю направления движения героя.

```
 void Update()
    {
    if(_kbhit())
    {   if (isKeyPressed('W'))
        {
            unitsArr[heroIndex].changeMoveDirectionTo(0, -1);
            moveUnitTo(&unitsArr[heroIndex]);
        }
        else if (isKeyPressed('S'))
        {
            unitsArr[heroIndex].changeMoveDirectionTo(0, 1);
            moveUnitTo(&unitsArr[heroIndex]);

        }
        else if (isKeyPressed('A'))
        {
            unitsArr[heroIndex].changeMoveDirectionTo(-1, 0);
            moveUnitTo(&unitsArr[heroIndex]);

        }
        else if (isKeyPressed('D'))
        {
            unitsArr[heroIndex].changeMoveDirectionTo(1, 0);
            moveUnitTo(&unitsArr[heroIndex]);
        }
    ...
    }
```

После этого захотел написать функцию, которая выводила бы на экран вопрос, и при помощи `_getch()` считывала бы ответ игрока (y/n)

```
bool getAnswerFromLogPanel(const string questionMessage)
{
    UpdateLog(questionMessage + " [Y]/[N]");

    const char inputAnswer = tolower(_getch());
    if (inputAnswer == 'y')
    {
        UpdateLog("[Y]");
        return true;
    }

    UpdateLog("[N]");
    return false;
}
```

Здесь столкнулся с проблемой, что `_getch()` не останавливает поток и не ждет нажатия клавиши.

При этом если использовать вместо `_getch()` функцию `getchar()` или `cin.get()` на экран консоли выводятся символы ранее нажатых клавиш.

[image: Пример вывода символов нажатых ранее нажатых клавиш]

[image: Пример вывода символов нажатых ранее нажатых клавиш]

Как я понял,`_getch()` просто считывает один символ из последних нажатых клавиш (те, которые выводит на экран `getchar()` или `cin.get()`) и поэтому не останавливает поток.

#### То что мне не помогло:

`cin.ignore()`, `cin.clear()`, `cin.sync()`, `system("cls")`, `fflush(stdin)`.

#### То что работает, но не так как надо:

1. Работает, но если до этого когда-то была нажата клавиша Y или N - ответ будет считываться с нее.

   ```
   do
   {
       char input = _getch();
       input = tolower(input);

       if (input == 'y')
      {
          UpdateLog("[Y]");
          return true;
      }

       if(input == 'n')
       {
           UpdateLog("[N]");
           return false;
       }
   } while (true);
   ```
2. При каждом срабатывании `_kbhit()` считывать при помощи `_getch()` символ с потока.
   Но тогда движение героя и реакция на нажатия клавиш значительно замедляется.

C++, Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Низкоуровневый ввод через GetAsyncKeyState совсем не дружит с потоковым вводом-выводом. Попробуйте читать ввод тоже через WinAPI-шные функции.

Comment: @VladD
Не подскажете, какие именно WinAPI-функции можно использовать в данном случае?

Comment: Думаю, вам должны подойти `ReadConsoleInput` и `FlushConsoleInputBuffer` ([документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684199(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: @VladD Спасибо. Всё работает.

Comment: Отлично, тогда оформлю в виде ответа.

Comment: А есть открытый исходники?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку потоковое чтение работает в конечном итоге через WinAPI-шные функции и не ожидает, что будет использован прямой доступ к тем же функциям, то оно не дружит с низкоуровневым вводом через `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Поэтому, если уж вы пользуетесь низкоуровневыми функциями, пользуйтесь ими всё время.

Для вашего случая, вам должны помочь [`FlushConsoleInputBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683147(v=vs.85).aspx) (чтобы сбросить буферизацию уже нажатых к текущему моменту клавиш) и [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961(v=vs.85).aspx). Вот [общая страница документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684199(v=vs.85).aspx), на всякий случай.